# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError why Rails ignore Strong_params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create 
        @post = Post.new(params[:post])
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end

    def show
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
    @posts=Post.all
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to improve your code (you've set your `index` and `show` methods as private!):

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create 
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
       @posts=Post.all
    end

    private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

As per the [strong params documenation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html), you need to call the private method with your strong params inside in order to pass them

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not using it.

Replace `params[:post]` with your method `post_params`.

Answer (score 0):

Make post_params method as private method but not other method

```
private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

Call it where you want to use like this.

```
def create 
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
end
```